# How can I implement webview background audio play on Vimeo in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

Now I can play videos from vimeo in react-native.

```
import WebView from 'react-native-autoheight-webview';

<WebView
allowsFullscreenVideo
scrollEnabled={false}
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
source={{
  html: `
    <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src="URL"></iframe>
        <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
        `
  }}
/>
```

I want to add background audio play function.

How can I do that?

Please give me any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue ...?

Comment: After all, I used react-native-video to implement background mode. They serve background mode.

Comment: i want to use it in youtube, i dont think react native video will help